# Brackets in jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, radio-button, show-hide

I'm having some trouble with my jquery, i can't really seam to get it to work.

I'm making a survey, and the last radio option in every question is other, so the user can enter a custom text if the like.
I would like the text box to be hidden until or if the radio is checked and the text box should a peer.

I have tried with this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#custom_form_custom_field_2_block").hide();

    $("input:radio[name=custom_form[custom_field_1]]").change(function () {
        if (this.value == "jeg har et helt 4. forslag") {
            $("#custom_form_custom_field_2_block").fadeIn();
        } else {
            $("#custom_form_custom_field_2_block").fadeOut();
        }

    });

    $("#custom_form_custom_field_2_block").focusout(function () {
        $("input:radio[name=Title]:checked").attr('value', $("#custom_form_custom_field_2_block").val());
    });
});
```

I have a link to mt fiddle here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thokoch/fFGJ5/)

Hope you can help,
Regards
Thomas

Comment: You have to enable jQuery in your jsFiddle. Use the menu bars to the left to choose the right version. Then run the Developer toolbars in Chrome/IE or Firebug in Firefox. The error is `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:radio[name=custom_form[custom_field_1]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this line is the problem:

```
$("input:radio[name=custom_form[custom_field_1]]")
```

Brackets ("[" and "]") are reserved characters in css selectors (you are passing such a selector to jQuery's $() function), and you are using brackets as part of your element's names. Try this instead:

```
$("input:radio[name=custom_form\\[custom_field_1\\]]")
```

Which yields a css selector of

```
input:radio[name=custom_form\[custom_field_1\]]
```

thus escaping the brackets. Might not work in all browsers.

Edit: Here's some additional info on escaping characters in css selectors:
http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes